# Everything in Finder sidebar disappeared (Macbook air 2019 Catalina 10.15.2)

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, data-recovery, finder

- My history of previous terminal codes:

[image]

- How my Finder looks like:

[image]

All the things in my finder sidebar disappeared, though nothing is deleted and I can still find my things through the "go" feature.

I've tried going through `Finder`>`Preferences`>`Sidebar` but nothing shows up. I was wondering if there is a terminal code to fix this, the only thing I did recently was put in a terminal code to prevent spotlight from searching my external hard drive (did this because I couldn't eject since a program was apparently using it, turns out it was spotlight search), and ever since then my finder sidebar disappeared.

What to do?

Comment: So what exactly is at Finder>Preferences>Sidebar ? Nothing... like no boxes to check or uncheck? Or are you just saying they are already checked?

Comment: They are already checked but it doesn't show up

Comment: I honestly don't know enough about macs to help... I think its fair to assume that the code you ran is what caused it... You could probably solve it by replacing the files you wrote to with the defaults if you could find them online, or maybe just remove the bits you added. Or you could go with the discrete option and just reset from factory settings.

Comment: "Switch it off then on again" Uncheck all the sidebar items in prefs, reboot, recheck them, reboot.  Actually, before you do that - hover your cursor over where it says Favourites. What does it say to the right?

Comment: Try the following commands in Terminal, and reboot your machine : "rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist" (no quotes) and "rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist" (ditto). After reboot, try to set new preferences for Finder and see if they stick.

Comment: LMAO IM ACTUALLY RETARDED. GENUINELY WAS FREAKING OUT OVER THIS. THANK UUUUUUUU @Tetsujin

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you hover over 'Favorites'? A button 'Show' should appear, to expand the list:

[image]